# Javascript object/function not working when calling DOM

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, getelementsbyclassname

I'm very beginner so I'm sorry if something doesn't make sense :)

I'm trying to search an XML DOM by ClassName, using a custom function which only seems to work when I'm searching the document the script is in.

This is the function:

```
Object.prototype.getElementsByClassName = function(getElementsByClass) {

function getElementsByClass(searchClass,node,tag) {

    var classElements = new Array();

    if ( node == null )
        node = document;
    if ( tag == null )
        tag = '*';
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp('(^|\\\\s)'+searchClass+'(\\\\s|$)');
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
            classElements[j] = els[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return classElements;

}

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET","somexml.xml",false);

xmlhttp.send();

xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

var foo = xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("gridCellAlt");
```

(I then output foo somewhere down later - the output all works fine.)

Now, everything works if I use `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName` and use a tag name - however, the page I am going to be accessing makes use of class names, so I want to use `xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName`.  The above script works completely fine if I use `var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("gridCellAlt");` and include the information I am accessing in the page running the script, but when I try to use it on the xmlDoc DOM it doesn't work. To sum it up: the only time the script doesn't work is when I'm using the xmlDoc (instead of document), and the `getElementsbyClassName` in conjunction.  If I use document and getElementsByClassName its fine.  If I use xmlDoc and get `elementsByTagName` its fine.

I'm thinking the `getElementsByClassName` isn't searching within the DOM nodes correctly, but even if I put `class="gridCellAlt"` somewhere in the root node of a test DOM it still doesn't find it.  I've tried adding more information behind `foo = xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("gridCellAlt", (info here))` but that doesn't seem to address the issue either.

Answer (score 2):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
            var foo = xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("gridCellAlt");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This. Because XMLHTTPRequest executes asynchronously, you need to check for when it returns successfully (readyState 4) and then operate on the XML (because it will have it by then). Otherwise, you have the potential of trying to operate on something that has not been initialized yet.

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem, as if I use xmlDoc.getElementsbyTagName("sometaghere"); I get results.  Its only when using my custom xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName where it doesn't find anything.  While this might be an issue and maybe is good to include into the script, I don't think that is what is causing my issue - also, adding it in testing did not solve the problem.